# Determine how long PHP executed so far

Tags: php, function

I need to determine how long a PHP function has been running so far.

What are some options to find out how long some PHP code takes to run?

I'm using zend framework.

Answer (score 38):

Call `microtime(true)` function to fetch current time with milisecond resolution.

```
<?php
$startTime = microtime(true);

/*stuff is going on*/

echo "Elapsed time is: ". (microtime(true) - $startTime) ." seconds";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but implementing that within a framework is not straightforward. besides, it's not accurate because the processing time used by the framework itself is not counted

Comment: I would expect you would need a real elapsed time, not an elapsed time - 'framework time'. As far as implementing it into existing code goes, the easiest (not necessarily the best) way could be using a singleton, to have the timer globally accessible.

Comment: Don't there need to be parenthesis around `microtime(true) - $startTime`?

Comment: @Nate You're quite right about that. `+`,`-` and `.` have the same operator precedence, and are left associative. This means first concatenation would be performed before subtraction.

Answer (score 6):

[microtime](https://www.php.net/microtime) — Return current Unix timestamp with microseconds

```
<?php
$time = microtime(TRUE);

//...code here...

print (microtime(TRUE)-$time). ' seconds';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use PHP's standard timeout, and implement a [shutdown](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) function.

```
function say_goodbye() {

    if (connection_status() == CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {
        ... do your special processing to save the process state here
        ... then formulate a response for the browser
    }
}   //  function say_goodbye()


register_shutdown_function("say_goodbye");
```

Note that you can set the shutdown function to accept parameters

**EDIT**

```
function say_goodbye($controller1,$controller2) {

    if (connection_status() == CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {
        ... do your special processing to save the process state here
        ... then formulate a response for the browser
    }
}   //  function say_goodbye()


$ctl1 = new DBController();
$ctl2 = new OPController();

register_shutdown_function("say_goodbye",$ctl1,$ctl2);
```

Comment: hmm, your suggestion is interesting but i'm having a problem saving the state of my process with this setup because within the shutdown function i cannot anymore access the variables of my framework's controllers

Comment: though, there's a possible workaround for this using globals but i'm still considering it. thanks anyway :)

Comment: You need to pass the $variables for the controllers to the shutdown function, which means you can only register it after they've been initialised... see edit. I actually use this method for trapping timeouts, and returning a response formatted by my outputController.

Comment: I'm not a zend framework user, so I don't know how well the method would work with that.

Answer (score 1):

One of quick and accurate snippet I can recommend.

```
//Block of my complex code
//...

echo 'Exact time taken to run: ' . (microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']) . ' seconds';
```