# How to check how long PHP script executed so far wrt. max_execution_time?

Tags: php

In documentation of max_execution_time we read that

> Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

If that is true, then simply using microtime as suggested in [Determine how long PHP executed so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796683/determine-how-long-php-executed-so-far) will not give you any clue about how close are you to the max execution time limit.

In some environments/languages there is a concept of a "soft" limit -- when it hits, the application gets notified, but is not terminated, and can react gracefuly. 
It seems to me that in PHP you have only a "hard" limit -- you are either before the deadline, or you smashed against the wall with "Maximum execution time of %d second%s exceeded" E_ERROR, which you can do nothing about.

What I wanted to do is to check from time-to-time how long the script executed so far, and manually handle graceful exit, when it is getting near the max execution time.

In a similar question [Detect when running time is near max_execution_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310375/detect-when-running-time-is-near-max-execution-time) motivated by similar issues, the accepted solution was to register a shutdown function -- this somewhat sidesteps the original problem, and does not really apply to my situation -- I want to handle the problem in the app context, not inside the shutdown handler.

From what I understand Zend/zend_execute_API.c the zend_set_timeout function uses
                struct itimerval t_r;           /* timeout requested */
                sigset_t sigset;

```
            if(seconds) {
                    t_r.it_value.tv_sec = seconds;
                    t_r.it_value.tv_usec = t_r.it_interval.tv_sec = t_r.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
                    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &t_r, NULL);
            }
            if(reset_signals) {
                    signal(SIGPROF, zend_timeout);
                    sigemptyset(&sigset);
                    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGPROF);
            }
```

From what I understand http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer this should measure both: user and system mode time. I'm getting confused here as it somewhat contradicts the PHP specs.
In the notes to the setitimer one can read that

> POSIX.1 leaves the interaction between setitimer() and the three
>   interfaces alarm(2), sleep(3), and usleep(3) unspecified.

which may explain why the following script does not exit after 5 (wall clock) seconds:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(5);
while(1){sleep(1);}
?>
```

Probably sleep does not count towards user-time nor system-time.

Comment: Something line a soft limit does not exist in php. Check if declared ticks can help you. ticks beeing more that some ms apart had some waiting inbetween.

Comment: Do you want the time WITH or without system calls? The first you can simply `$now - $startDate`, the second, you can measure the time a system call took and subtract from the summed time, easy as that

Comment: My motivation actually requires the same way the PHP counts the time toward the max_execution_limit. As the spec does not clarify how exactly is it measured, I am unable to clarify my question :( From my experminets it is neither the CPU time, nor wallclock time, nor the user time. It seems to be something like a wallclock time minus the time wasted for I/O.

Comment: OK, perhaps this is user-mode time. Still, how to measure user-mode time then? Your idea of subtracting is quite unrealistic in the app this large as in mine case -- I would have to instrument a bazilion  of places